# ajax call to server with self signed certificates.

Tags: angularjs, jquery, ssl, https, http-headers

I need to make an ajax call to a server which uses a self-signed certificate. 
Using the --insecure option does in curl helps in doing so.

But i need to make ajax calls, much like the $http requests in angular js. Are there any headers that can be set so that the error of the certificate does not arise.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565772/ajax-calls-to-untrusted-https-fail-silently

Comment: or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580508/getting-chrome-to-accept-self-signed-localhost-certificate

Answer (score 1):

There is a very hackish way in which you can point your browser in the direction of the server resource. This will prompt you to proceed with caution and upon proceeding anyway (try it with Chrome), your queries to the server should now work since the browser will now remember that that particular certificate is okay. I had this issue in the last project I worked on with self signed certs.

Comment: can you give an example of hackish way?