# Accept non secure responses from secure $http request in Angular

Tags: angularjs, https, get

I am making a $get request to a secure server in Angular. The problem is this is an internal server (which I have no control over) with a bad certificate and as a result I am getting mixed content error messages and my browser is not allowing the response to be displayed for security reasons.

Anything I can do to request data by HTTPS but also make sure I accept a non secure response?

```
$.get('https://internal.domain.com' + '' + $scope.account, function (data, status) {
    _.forEach(data, function (item) {
      $rootScope.hotNews.push(item);
    });
  });
```

Comment: Sadly, this is not possible. This post answer most of it :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565772/ajax-calls-to-untrusted-self-signed-https-fail-silently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, I found out its not possible... :(